# Launch JavaScript script from auto Process

Tags: javascript, process-builder, automation, heroku

The requirement is to build PDF in an automate process on records.

My solution is to build kind of API on Heroku that will render PDF using a external Framework.

I am wondering if there is any way I can execute JavaScript on specific records in an Auto process, to generate the PDF using an external Framework.

In the same way that process builder runs and automatically updates records, I would like to run JavaScript script on the specific records.

edit:
I know that I can do it with Process Builder and Heroku, I am wondering if there is an easier way to do that, without heroku. Maybe with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that your PDF generation is hosted on Heroku then you don't need to execute JavaScript from the Process Builder, you need to do Callout.

Here I found an example of how you can do it
http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/03/invoking-apex-callout-from-process.html

Comment: I know that I can do it with Process Builder and Heroku, I am wondering if there is an easier way to do that, without heroku. Maybe with JavaScript.

Comment: Salesforce will launch Salesforce Functions in future but it is in beta right now. this will definitely useful in your case. read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_functions.htm&type=5&release=230